# Trying to execute update-alternatives command specified in an instrutional document

Tags: java

I am trying to execute the following command

```
sudo update-alternatives "/usr/local/bin/java" "java" "/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java"
```

But I keep receiving the error message

```
update-alternatives: error: unknown argument `/usr/local/bin/java'
```

What might I do to successfully do what this command means to do?

(This is to setup an android environment for a in-class lab, I by no means understand what I am doing or what this command means to do, I just need to get it done...)

I have looked and the file "/usr/local/bin/java" does not exist on my system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st thing you need to supply is an argument. According to [`man update-alternatives`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) those can be ...

> Synopsis
>
> alternatives [options] **--install** link name path priority [--slave
>   link name path]... [--initscript service]
>
> alternatives [options] **--remove** name path
>
> alternatives [options] **--set** name path
>
> alternatives [options] **--auto** name
>
> alternatives [options] **--display** name
>
> alternatives [options] **--config** name

as you can see the parameter is obligatory. According to the [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) you can use `sudo update-alternatives --config java`. This will present you with a selection that looks similar to the following (the details may differ for you):

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).  
Selection Path Priority Status 
———————————————————— 
* 0 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java 1061 auto mode 
1 /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/jre/bin/java 3 manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
```

Yours probably needs to be:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/local/bin/java" "java" "/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java" 1
```

Comment: Viewing this tutorial (first page near the bottom) http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/c6053/lectures/PDF/environ.pdf Do you think I should use --install?

Comment: yes see the additions :) Mind the 1 at the end. according to the wiki you need that too

Comment: Well it did things... Hopefully I can get it all back when I am done with this lab. Thanks!